How to edit YouTube videos ? I am mainly interested in special Pro-Editing
Generally in YouTube, we listen to songs of films. Now the songs of any film are lyrical with no video and also sometimes are lyrical with videos.
When we are listening to a lyrical video song of any film, then generally the video consists of the pictures of the "Hero" and the "Heroine" of that film.
But suppose I want to cut the pictures of the "Hero" and the "Heroine" and I want to paste my Father's and my Mother's pictures in their place.
Is it possible to do that ? If, then how can I do that ?
Day after tomorrow I am having my Mother's Birthday. I really want to surprise her with this thing.
Please inform me if anyone know.

Please anyone reply if they know. I really want to surprise my Mom with this.

If I understand your question: there is a video on YouTube which consists of still images and has continuous audio. You wish to replace the still images with images of your parents.
This is an outline of steps which you could take. How easy it is to do will depend on your access to software and knowledge of how to use it.

Download the video from YouTube. This can be accomplished using browser plugins, online services, or dedicated software. Note that downloading videos from YouTube which are not your property is a violation of YouTube's Terms of Service.
Import the video into video editing software. Examples are Adobe Premiere Pro, Apple Final Cut Pro, Shotcut, Microsoft Clipchamp, iMovie, and Lightworks.
Import the still pictures of your parents into the video editor.
Open the video file in your video editor. You should see a timeline-style display of the video and audio tracks.
Place the images in the timeline where you want them to appear. If you want to completely remove all other still pictures, delete the imported video track and replace it with a new track containing your images.
Compile and render the video into a video format such as MP4 or MOV.

Each video editing application will have its own ways to accomplish this. This workflow outline is not specific to any particular software, although it is based on my knowledge of Adobe Premiere Pro and Adobe AfterEffects.
